# Unable to fetch list of Azure Resources via Postman

Tags: postman, azure-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the list of resources present in my Azure Resource Group.

To do that, I got an access token by registering one app in Azure AD using the client_credentials flow.

But when I am using that token to query like below, I'm getting `401 Unauthorized` - Authentication failed error.

**Query that I used:**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/resources?api-version=2021-04-01
```

I have owner access to all my resources but why am I getting 401 Unauthorized error. Is there any step that I missed?

Can anyone point me in a right path?

Answer (score 0):

I came to know I have to give API permissions for **Azure Service Management**.

After giving user_impersonation, I changed the scope to `https://management.azure.com/.default` and got access token.

Using this token, I successfully got the list of resources without any errors.